# How to accept the git push? Is git suitable to send full project on github? Shall i use other method, which? Ssh?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

Updated question ( i do not create a separate branch, use decault procedure, and do not use sudo ). It gives me two branches on git : main and master, but it shows only one branch on localmachine *master. How to merge master with the main on the github?

```
$ sudo git init // i have change permissions for .git to writable, do not use sudo anymore
$ git add -all
$ git remote add origin "https://github.com/gintares/jokes2"
$ git commit -m "first"
$ git push -u origin master

$ git branch
* master
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION
i was creating a different branch
and was using git with sudo ( it is not recommended )

How to get the git repository pull requests approved?

I have created a new git repository, and new project on my computer.

```
htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git init

htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git add --all
htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git remote add origin "https://github.com/gintares/jokes"
htdocs/jokes_any$ git remote -v // And double check to make sure it know
htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git checkout -b jokes

htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git commit -m "first"

htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git push -u origin jokes

htdocs/jokes_any$ sudo git remote -v
         
origin  https://github.com/gintares/jokes (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/gintares/jokes (push)
htdocs/jokes_any$
```

It is under this link https://github.com/gintares/jokes

It looks like commit, versus files and folders. I am not able to find where i can accept the push?

I can see compare & pull request button, it opens the new window with all pushed files. Nevertheless, these files are not under https://github.com/gintares/jokes , they are under https://github.com/gintares/jokes/compare/jokes?expand=1

How to accept the push?

Shall i send the files to git over shell, and push changes later? I mean is git suitable to send full project on github?  Shall i use other method, which? Shall i use git ssh https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh?

Comment: Are you asking about creating a pull request for your `jokes` branch?

Comment: I am not sure what means pull request - i do not intend to pull files from git to localhost. I want to upload the project files to the git from my local computer. The files i send with push are on the 'innitial commit'. It is not possible to download them. How to transfer them to the https://github.com/gintares/jokes ?

Comment: i have tried ssh, but i am getting error '> Permission denied (publickey).', https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign

Comment: I see the branch here and your "first" commit: https://github.com/gintares/jokes/tree/jokes. So I'm still confused then.

Comment: how to see this commit on github.com/gintares/jokes ?  That others could download it ? I believe there shall be a command or feature 'accept commit'. I do not see it. Maybe i push the project in wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, your commit is inside your `jokes` branch. So you have to switch branches. You did do a `git checkout -b jokes` after all. If you do `git branch` you should see `main` and `jokes` with a * on the latter.

Until you merge that branch into `master`, you won't see it.  If you're trying to merge then then do a pull request.

Comment: i have no master, only *jokes

Comment: The problem stems from how to initialize and such. You had created one commit to `main` branch. However, you never pull those in. As a result, it's confused. The "first" commit is connected with `jokes`. You can see that `jokes` is one commit behind:
https://github.com/gintares/jokes/branches. The `git init` really screw up this your folder. Are you sure you didn't have another folder that you had set-up `git` with?

The problem is that you initialize. This screw everything up.

Comment: how to initialise correct? i am trying to create another git to start over - github.com/gintares/jokes2 – Gintare Statkute . I have updated the question with commands i was using to create the new reository. It gives me two branches on git : main and master, but it shows only one branch on localmachine *master. How to merge master with the main on the github?

Comment: See below for my other answer.

Comment: thank you. I have switched main and master for jokes2 repository and it worked, i can see all files now, i have pushed to the *master.

Comment: But, i do not understand how to initialise correct. I do not create main repository, why there are two main repositories on github?

Comment: When you create a GitHub repo, you have already initialize. So the initiation that you did locally only conflict in the end. You should clone when you have created. You only do `git init` if you didn't have a GitHub repo and you wanted to start from scratch from a local `git` repo.

Answer (score 1):

You should never `git init` locally if you already have a GitHub repo. You should `git clone` it to your local computer. That will have all the branches in places.

1. Create a separate folder on your machine that is independent of what you have
2. This folder should entirely be empty
3. Type `git clone https://github.com/gintares/jokes` or your jokes2 repo.
4. Now if you want to create a separate branch then do `git checkout -b jokes`. Otherwise commit directly to `main`.
5. Move those files that you had over to this path
6. Proceed with `git add --all`
7. `git commit -m "first"` and `git push`
8. You should then be able to do a PR if you had a `jokes` branch.

Comment: Note that you don't need to `git remote origin...`. Git clone will set it up entirely.

Answer (score 0):

i have find out this working solution:

```
$ sudo git init // change permissions for created new folder `.git` to writable, do not use sudo anymore
$ git add -all
$ git remote add origin "https://github.com/gintares/jokes2"
$ git commit -m "first"
$ git push -u origin master

$ git branch
* master
```

than go to the git, and switch *master branch with main branch. Click on the branches, than click switch.

not working variations:
1)

```
$ git push -u origin main
```

gives error that main branch does not exists

2)

```
git checkout -b main
git push -u origin main
```

gives error:
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

3)

```
git checkout -b main
git pull origin main
git push -u origin main
```

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gintares/jokes3'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Note that when you do `git init` and you `git commit`, it by default creates a `master` branch. `git` hasn't been updated to the latest philosophy to use `main`. That's why there is a `main` and `master`. But you can rename a branch. See: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-rename-local-and-remote-git-branch/